# C++: cannot initialize a variable of type 'char**' with a rvalue of type 'char*[x]'

Tags: c++, string, pointers, memory

```
char str_arr[] = "ads";
char *str_ptr = str_arr;

char **ptr_str_ptr = &str_ptr;     // OK
char **ptr_str_arr = &str_arr;     // compile error: cannot initialize a variable of type 'char**' with a rvalue of type 'char*[4]'
```

I'm confused why we cannot get the address of `str_arr`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get the address of `str_arr`. However, it would be an address of an array, not an address of a pointer. Essentially, the assignment fails because the types are not compatible.

Here is one illustration of why you cannot assign it to a pointer to pointer to `char`, because this would be possible:

```
char **ptr_str_arr = &str_arr; // imagine this has worked
*ptr_str_arr = new char[10];   // This cannot be done to an array
```

This would not work even for `const` pointers, either, because of type incompatibility.

```
char* const* ptr_const_str_arr = &str_arr; // Does not work either
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/r2JTDX)